# Construct 3-Sheave Pulleys for Hanging Objects from Rafters

Tags: steel, hanging, design

I am trying to create a system of 2 3-sheave pulleys (along with terminal pulleys) that can hoist my hanging plants up to my rafters, such as here:

[image: Hanging Plants] [image: Shaves]

I am happy with my general design but what I am uncertain about is the design of the pulleys along the wall, the ones that redirect the forces right and then down.

I have designed a system with a 5/16" shoulder screw, 4 washers and 3 plastic sheaves 11/32" wide and 3/4" in diameter - I'll be using 1/4" jute as rope. (While the diagram shows that the sheaves are recessed near the centers in actuality they are flush across and will likely not rub with the washers in place.

[image: Shave Setup]

My question is is my pulley design good, or will the transverse forces likely warp, or snap, the screws (I have both stainless steel (40,000 PSI sheer strength) and alloy steel (86,000 PSI) available to me; which is best for pine and the forces here?)? These 5/16" shoulder screws have a 7/16" thread length and 1/4" thread width. The depth the screw penetrates the wood is also a factor I need to figure out - what is the deepest it needs go? The wood is pine. Each plant will weigh no more than 20 lbs; I figure not more than 100 N lift on each.

If this system does not work could there be a work around such as putting a cage around the pulleys?

Comment: Welcome Jesse, you have beautiful diagrams there. Although I cannot expertly answer your main question (an expert will be along shortly) I feel there is another consideration. As the cords enter and leave the pulleys that change the direction, make sure it doesn't chafe or rub on the edge of the pulley. Or the cord will fray and fail.

Comment: I would be inclined to use structural scews and use a sleeve for the axle. structual screws are very strong. and attach well to wood.

Comment: My initial "shade tree" non-engineer impression is that 3/4" pulleys will be undersized. You will need to apply over 40 lbs. of force just to lift the load...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it any idea how big a sheave I should get? I can get larger ones, which also come with larger center holes.

Comment: @Jasen how much depth into the wood would you recommend the screws go?

Comment: I am picturing the mounting hole in a 3/4" pulley and just don't think a hefty enough fastener would fit. Your system has no mechanical advantage, all the pulleys are just direction changes. The system will be subject to the weight of the load x 2 just to lift it + friction from multiple direction changes. You will need robust hardware with sturdy mounting.

Comment: I have found other pulleys of the same type: [1 1/2" diameter with 1/2" center hole](https://www.shopsoundboatworks.com/roacsobe11ro2.html), [1 15/16" diameter with 11/32" center hole](https://www.shopsoundboatworks.com/roacsobe115r.html). I would prefer the first since it is cheaper (and it does fit a wider fastener), but if 1 1/2" is also not big enough I would rather spend extra to get something that works. These pulleys are Ronstan Acetal Solid Bearing type. These are supposed to be strong and low friction.

Comment: hmm pine and a fairly light load, I'd reccomend they go at-least as far in as they stick out

Comment: I am going to attempt using 1/2" shoulder screws 3 3/4" long with a 3/8" thread 5/8" long. I will use 3 - 1 1/2" diameter sheaves, 19/32" wide. I will post my results as an answer once I have tested this.